# Limit of a rational function $\left(\frac{5n^2+4}{3n^2+n+1}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove with the $\epsilon-N$ definition that the sequence $\left(\frac{5n^2+4}{3n^2+n+1}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent to $\frac{5}{3}$.

We have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left|\frac{5n^2+4}{3n^2+n+1}-\frac{5}{3}\right| &= \left|\frac{15n^2+12-15n^2-5n-5}{3(3n^2+n+1)}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{7-5n}{3(3n^2+n+1)}\right| < \epsilon.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
My question is how do we rearrange this fraction in terms of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\frac{7-5n}{3(3n^2+n+1)}| \leq \frac{7n+5n}{n^2}=\frac{12}{n}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {|7-5n|} {3(3n^{2}+n+1)}\leq \frac {6n} {9n^{2}}$ provided $n >7$. Hence $\frac {|7-5n|} {3(3n^{2}+n+1)} <\epsilon$ if $n>7$ and $\frac 2 {3n} <\epsilon$. So take $n>7$ and $n >\frac 2 {3\epsilon}$.